# How to cause latex to exit immediately if a file in \input{somelatex} is missing?

Tags: formatting

I have an `abbrev.tex` file that used in another file `project.tex` through

```
\input{abbrev}
```

Today for some reason, `abbrev.tex` is missing (I may have deleted it accidentally).
I tried compile `project.tex` using `pdflatex` and it keeps complaining that command not found.

I wasted about 30 mins before I realized that that perpetual `abbrev.tex` is missing.

If `pdflatex` crashes immediately if it cannot find `abbrev.tex` then it will help me
to locate the source of the problem.

Is there a way to cause `pdflatex` to just die when it cannot find a file?

Comment: `\InputIfFileExists{yourfile.tex}{}{\batchmode \read -1 to \x }`

Comment: Input complains immediately, so where is the problem here? Never ignore compilation errors

Comment: A missing file cannot lead to an error about "_command not found_". But as daleif pointed out, a file not found raises an error immediately, so it's not clear to me how it could take 30 minutes to find that out. Are you by any chance using some LaTeX editor? Those tend to hide errors...

Comment: Phelype Oleinik, What does it do? what is \read -1 to \x?

Comment: Phelype Oleinik, it works like magic.

Comment: latex already stops with an error message and waits for a user response on a missing file, What else do you want it to do?  @PhelypeOleinik's suggestion makes teh error non recoverable so it is ompossible to opt to carry on past that point.

Comment: @campa: a missing file can cause very misleading error since \input or \include line is replaced by an empty line if a file is missing. When I have many files and dependencies, bad things may just happen.

Comment: No input does not do that, it stops. Again please explain exactly what you're doing and how you're compiling.

Comment: @EdGan It was not a really serious solution.  It does what you ask, but people don't always know what's best for them :)  As others said, `\input` already complains on a file not found, telling you the name of the guilty file, so you shouldn't need more than that to debug.  The trick in my comment puts TeX in `\batchmode` (no terminal output and no user interaction), then `\read -1 to \x` tries to read something from the terminal;  since user interaction is off, TeX exits immediately.  But that gives you absolutely no clue on what file is missing!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you are right. After playing with it, I decide to drop it since it gives no clue where it breaks. I have been using LaTex for a long time and only now I see No file abbrev.tex in the compilation window but it is hiding in tonnes of lines. Unless one is so patient to read every compile line  LaTeX  compile every time they compile a file and look for warning messages...  Everything is there but it is not obvious where things break in the most transparent way.

Comment: @daleif   No input does not do that, it stops. Umm. this is not what I see or know.

Comment: @EdGan glad we could convince you not to do that :-)  Regarding looking for errors:  I find it much easier to spot errors by using the command line to run LaTeX, so it stops on each error.  Regardless, if you are using the log you can search for `Error` and it will most likely take you to something that needs attention

Comment: Aarghh sorry, \input will crash immediately. But I have used \include

Comment: As a casual user for years, I do not pay attention to the diff between \input and \include.  It seems I should avoid using \include then.

Comment: The top answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include     did miss the \input behavior about crashing.